# Thinking about singularities and the speed of light

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, speed-of-light, mass-energy, singularities

I apologize that this takes so much explanation. From what I understand about the idea of the "singularity" in a black hole, it's not taken literally as Infinite mass in zero density or whatever it means exactly. More likely, singularities or infinities are where the equations break from reality, as I've understood.

Given that thought, I was thinking about the oft repeated idea that reaching the speed of light requires infinite energy for any massive object. Given what I have stated above (assuming I'm not mistaken) could this energy requirement simply be where the equations break down rather than reality? Perhaps there is actually an extreme amount of energy that could accelerate matter to the speed of light?

Comment: The fact that the answer to the question is “no” doesn’t justify a downvote. Are only “yes” questions allowed on this site? +1

Answer (score 1):

In this case the infinity is different. In a black hole singularity, or in the self energy of the electron, you find actual infinities. But in having c as the speed limit, you are only saying that you cannot reach c, because you would need infinite energy. So the theory is not introducing an  actual infinity, it is only saying that you cannot reach c (unless you don't have rest mass).

Comment: but a massive object approaches c as it accelerates and will do so in an asymptotic manner, infinitely approaching c. That's the infinity I mean. I'm merely relating the ideas I've read about relativity and black hole equations to relativity and relativistic travel through space in which massive objects cannot reach the c.  My only curiosity is concerning if this infinite energy is reality or if it's just a product of suboptimal equations and observations? I had read before that that singularitie and infinities are often signs of problems with the equations (as with relativity and black holes

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that's the same. In our universe, velocities v and w add together as shown in the equation.  You can prove to yourself that if v and w are much less than c, this approximates V = v + w.  You can also show that for any two velocities less than c, the sum V is necessarily less than c.  And if you set w=c, and add some velocity v to it, you get back V=c.  So c behaves more like "infinity" than it does like a real number in this type of scenario.

There is an even easier way to achieve c than adding infinite energy – just take away the mass.  All massless particles travel at c, with finite energy.

In!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/blVun.jpg)

Comment: But my question is, is the infinity actually real or just a product of the best equations were have?

Comment: Well, it's the best equations we have.  Obviously we cannot accelerate a particle to infinite speed to test this, but every observation we've made so far of very high speed things matches the curve, so we don't have a reason to doubt it yet.